# Markov Chain and Random Walks

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

I am having difficulty understanding the question here. It says that $\{X_n\mid n=0,1,2,...\}$ is a simple random walk on the integers $S=\{\dots,-2,1,0,1,2,\dots\}$,starting at $X_0=3$. The probabilities of jumping left and right are $1/2$.

Let $T=\min{n\mid X_n=-3\text{ or }Xn=7}$.

(a) Find $E[X(T-2)]$.

(b) Find $E[X(T+2)]$.

I was wondering if I should put $T=4$ here since the minimum no of transitions to reach $-3$ or $7$ from $3$ is $4$. But then it would be straightforward as $E[X(2)]$ and $E[X(4)]$ which I believe should be $3$ in both cases. I think I am missing something [I was thinking whether I should try $\sum_xP(X>x)$]. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: $T$ is random, you can't set it equal to any particular number. It is the first time when the random walker hits some specific points (I am not sure whether the "3" in there was a typo; if not, then I think you want to restrict to $n>0$, otherwise $T$ is just $0$ and the problem is trivial.) However, it is possible to determine the distribution of $X(T)$ and then go forward or backward in time to get the distribution of $X(T+c)$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: However you can be a bit more slick, bypassing the need to compute any distributions, by noticing that $E[X(T+c)]=E[X(T)]$; why should that be? (In fact you can be *even more* slick if you know the optional stopping theorem, which enables you to immediately read off $E[X(T)]$ itself, but that may be beyond your current level.)

Comment: oh sorry....it's hitting either -3 or 7

Comment: @Ian it's not clear to me why $E[X(T+c)]=E[X(T)]$ when $c$ is negative? $T+c$ is not a stopping time in that case.

Comment: @dancm You're right, that was a mistake. I was thinking of the fact that the increments from each fixed time have mean zero, but for instance $X(T)-X(T-1)$ does not necessarily have mean zero. For example if the boundaries are at $-1$ and $2$, then you move left with probability $2/3$ and right with probability $1/3$ in the last step, so the average increment is $-1/3$. So you have to do $E[X(T-2)]$ "manually", by unraveling where the walk could have been at time $T-2$. I guess since it's just $T-2$ instead of a bigger shift, this is not a complicated procedure.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very nice exercise to show that $\mathbb P(X_T=7)=\frac{3}{5}$ and $\mathbb P(X_T=-3)=\frac{2}{5}$. As a hint:

> Let $h_n$ be the probability of hitting $7$ before $-3$ when you start
>  out at $X_0=n$, and set up a system for $h_n$, which you can solve
>  with the boundary conditions $h_7=1$ and $h_{-3}=0$.

As a consequence, we have
$$\mathbb E[X_T]=\frac{3}{5}\times7+\frac{2}{5}\times(-3)=3.$$
Now note that if $S_1, S_2$ are the two steps you take after $X_T$, then
$$\mathbb E[X_{T+2}]=\mathbb E[X_T+S_1+S_2]=\mathbb E[X_T]+\mathbb E[S_1]+\mathbb E[S_2]=\mathbb E[X_T]+0+0=\mathbb E[X_T]=3.$$
The case for $T-2$ is a bit trickier -- we can't immediately apply a similar argument as above, because, conditional on the fact that we hit $-3$ or $7$ two steps later, the increments may no longer distributed uniformly over $\pm1$.

We do have the following work around though. Note that $X_{T-2}$ is either $-1$ or $5$. Further, $X_{T-2}=-1$ iff $X_T=-3$ and $X_{T-2}=5$ iff $X_T=7$. So
$$\mathbb E[X_{T-2}]=\frac35\times5+\frac25\times(-1)=2.6.$$

---

What's going on under the hood here is that the simple random walk $X_n$ is an example of what is called a *martingale*, that is $X_n$ has the property
$$\mathbb E[X_{n+1}\mid X_n,\dots,X_1]=X_n.$$
For the random walk, this is obvious -- at each step, we are equally likely to move one space left or right. Martingales also have the property that
$$\mathbb E[X_n]=\mathbb E[X_{n-1}]=\dots=\mathbb E[X_0],$$
which again is especially obvious in the case of a simple random walk. For general martingales, you can prove this via the law of total expectation.

In general, if $\tau$ is a stopping time, and $M_n$ is a martingale, then the *optional stopping theorem* tells us that, so long as $\tau$ and $M_n$ satisfy some certain "finiteness" properties, then it is in fact true that $\mathbb E[M_\tau]=\mathbb E[M_0]$. This applies in the case of the simple random walk $X_n$ and our stopping time $T$, so we instantly know that $\mathbb E[X_T]=\mathbb E[X_0]$.

The fact that $\mathbb E[X_{T-2}]\neq\mathbb E[X_0]$ is because, as noted in the comments, $T-2$ is not a valid stopping time.